# how does web.xml knows a servlet present in a specific jar

Tags: java, web-applications

I am using web application in which jar files are there in lib folder. In web.xml, servlet class is provided.how does web.xml knows in which jar file that specific class is there???

Comment: Well application will scan classpath and with classloader mechanism it will know this thinkg.http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-classloader-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is handled by the classloader mechanism:

> A JAR file usually contains a "manifest" -- a file which lists the
>   contents of the JAR. The manifest can define a JAR-class-path, which
>   further extends the class path (but only while loading classes from
>   that JAR). Classes accessed by a JAR-class-path are found in the
>   following order:
>
> In general, classes referenced by a JAR-class-path entry are found as
>   though they were part of the JAR file. The JAR files that appear in
>   the JAR-class-path are searched after any earlier class path entries,
>   and before any entries that appear later in the class path. However,
>   if the JAR-class-path points to a JAR file that was already searched
>   (for example, an extension, or a JAR file that was listed earlier in
>   the class path) then that JAR file will not be searched again. (This
>   optimization improves efficiency and prevents circular searches.) Such
>   a JAR file is searched at the point that it appears, earlier in the
>   class path. If a JAR file is installed as an extension, then any
>   JAR-class-path it defines is ignored. All the classes required by an
>   extension are presumed to be part of the SDK or to have themselves
>   been installed as extensions.

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

The magic word in this case is class path .

The book "Learning in Java" describes this nicely.

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-java/1565927184/ch03s03.html

Java CLASSPATH variable, holds a list of locations that can be searched for packages containing Java class files. The Java interpreter and Java compiler use CLASSPATH when searching for packages and classes on the local host.

Just like we add directory location to path variable in dos/linux we can specify the location of jars in classpath variable.
Java also provided some default locations that it will look in. For example **the ext directory.** The path of ext folder in java on a windows installation may look like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\ext" . 
You can put your jars in the ext folder and class files in them will be automatically located..

A location on the class path can be a directory name or the name of a class archive file. Java supports archives of class files in its own Java archive ( JAR) format . This allows large groups of classes to be distributed in a single file; the Java interpreter automatically extracts individual class files from an archive,when required.

**The Java interpreter knows how to find core classes, which are the classes included in every Java installation. For example , the classes in the java.lang, java.io etc. Their location need not be put in class path, the Java interpreter can find them by itself.
To find other classes, the Java interpreter searches the locations on the class path in order.**

For example consider a search for the class vehicle.cars.Porche. Searching the class path directory /usr/lib/java means the interpreter looks for an individual class file at /usr/lib/java/vehicle/cars/Porche.class. If the class is present in a jar file say CompanyVehicle.jar  then the compiler will be looking for vehicle.cars.Porche.class in the CompanyVehicle.jar.

**To sum it up , Java has a list of location it knows it should look into. Other than that, it will look into locations you provide in classpath variable.**

if you want to understand more about how classpath, classloaders work behind the scene check out the links below

[How JVM starts looking for classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934780/how-jvm-starts-looking-for-classes)

http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-class-loader/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)

Comment: Please do not simply copy texts from books.

Comment: What I meant was, that you should mark text as being a quote and supply a source. Take a look at the other answer so see what I'm talking about.