# How compilers handle modules in programming languages

Tags: compiler-construction

A compiler takes the source code of a language and converts it into machine code or bytecode.

But, in the process, how does it handle modules. I mean there is include/import or whatever keyword the language has at the top of the file. How it finds that (required) module mentioned in the import statement in the file system.

As per my knowledge after syntax analysis during the code generation source code is converted to bytecode or assembly code. But I'm confused how the compiler jumps to the required module

Comment: see also [how JVM starts looking for classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8934780/how-jvm-starts-looking-for-classes)

Answer (score 0):

The straight solution is simply passing paths to the compiler and let it search the relevant files.

A different, more indirect approach is advocated by Oberon and its descendants (Java, C#). Originally [Oberon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon_(programming_language)) looked up the modules with namespace in a database. Java simplified that to a classpath ( a list of directories with namespace mapped to subdirectories), and C# resolves files over the [GAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac).